# "-webkit-" (a CSS property) isn't working in any browser except google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I used few -webkit- properties in my project for making the rounded tab box, animation and rotation stuff. However, I could implement javascript to get the task done. Since -webkit- offers very simple code formate and avoid a lot of coding, I got loved to use it. Now, while opening the page in chorome works fine, but other web browser like IE, Mozila can't detect it. It doesn't make any round-shaped box or any animation. How to fix that within my existing html and css code?

.PHP class:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Fatah's Homepage</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header id="top_header" >
<h1>Welcome to my world!</h1>
<div id="style_slogan">
<h1 id="header_slogan"><i>Raise your hand, Make A change</i></h1>
</div>
</header>
<div id="giant_wrapper">
<div id="top_menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#home"><div id="rollover_box_home"><p id="text_shadow_home">HOME</p></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#who_im"><div id="rollover_box_who_im">WHO I'M</div></a></li>
<li><a href="#gallery"><div id="rollover_box_gallery">GALLERY</div></a></li>
<li><a href="#diary"><div id="rollover_box_diary">MY DIARY</div></a></li>
<li><a href="#blog"><div id="rollover_box_blog">FATAH'S BLOG</div></a></li>
<li><a href="#contact"><div id="rollover_box_contact">CONTACT ME</div></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="new_div">
<section id="main_section">
<!--This div section is for main contaents for my website. All the correcponding 
text and paragraph will be added here-->
<div id="all_contents">
<div id="home">
<p>You are very welcome to my personal homepage. This is my very first creation over the web.
</p>
</div>
<div id="who_im">
<p>
my name is jabir and i was living in a small village.</b>

</p>
</div>
<div id="gallery">
<p> It's Gallery.</p>
</div>
<div id="diary">
<p> It's diary.</p>
</div>
<div id="blog">
<p> It's my blog.</p>
</div>
<div id="contact">
<p> contact info.</p>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
<footer id="the_footer">
Developed by Jabir Al Fatah 2014
</footer>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

.CSS class:

```
/*@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');*/
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
h1{
font:bold 20px Tahoma;
font-size:27px;
}
#header_slogan{
font-size:22px;
color:#CCFF00;
font: bold  22px Century Gothic;
}
#rollover_box_home{
display:block;
border:3px solid blue;
background:orange;
/*background:-webkit-radial-gradient(center, circle, red 0%, orange 50%);*/
/*background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, black, white);*/
padding:2px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-box-shadow:rgb(110, 110, 110) 5px 5px inset;
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1s;
}
#rollover_box_home:hover{
-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg);
}
#rollover_box_who_im{
display:block;
border:3px solid blue;
background:orange;
padding:2px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-box-shadow:rgb(110, 110, 110) 5px 5px inset;
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1s;
}
#rollover_box_who_im:hover{
-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg);
}
#rollover_box_gallery{
display:block;
border:3px solid blue;
background:orange;
padding:2px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-box-shadow:rgb(110, 110, 110) 5px 5px inset;
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1s;
}
#rollover_box_gallery:hover{
-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg);
}
#rollover_box_diary{
display:block;
border:3px solid blue;
background:orange;
padding:2px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-box-shadow:rgb(110, 110, 110) 5px 5px inset;
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1s;
}
#rollover_box_diary:hover{
-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg);
}
#rollover_box_blog{
display:block;
border:3px solid blue;
background:orange;
padding:2px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-box-shadow:rgb(110, 110, 110) 5px 5px inset;
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1s;
}
#rollover_box_blog:hover{
-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg);
}
#rollover_box_contact{
display:block;
border:3px solid blue;
background:orange;
padding:2px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-box-shadow:rgb(110, 110, 110) 5px 5px inset;
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1s;
}
#rollover_box_contact:hover{
-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg);
}
#text_shadow_home{

text-shadow:rgb(110,110,110) 3px 3px 5px;
}
h2{
font:bold 14px Tahoma;
}
header,section,footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup{
display:block;
}
body{
width:100%;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
background-color:#003300;
}
#wrapper{
max-width:1000px;
margin:20px auto;
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient:vertical;
-webkit-box-flex:1;
}
#top_header{
background:green;
border:3px solid orange;
padding:20px;
text-align:center;
}
#top_menu{
background:black;
color:white;
border:3px solid #FF0000 ;
padding:4px;
text-align:center;
}
#top_menu li{
display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
padding:5px;
font:bold 14px Tahoma;
}
#new_div{
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
}
#main_section{
border:1px solid blue;
-webkit-box-flex:1;
margin:20px;
padding:20px;
background:#996600

}
#the_footer{
color:black;
text-align:center;
padding:20px;
border-top: 2px solid red;
background-color:gray;
}
#all_contents >div {
display:none;
}
#all_contents{
background-color:#00FFFF;
border:10px solid #0000FF;
padding:8px;
-webkit-border-radius:20px;
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 2s;
}
#all_contents:hover{
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
}
#home{
font-size:20px;
}
#who_im{
font-size:20px;
}
```

.JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#all_contents>div').filter(':first').show();
$('ul>li>a').click(function () {
        $('#all_contents>div').hide();
        var $this = $(this);
        var target = $this.attr('href');
        $(target).show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: for chrome it is -webkit-
for firefox it is -moz-
like that see what are the specifications of different browsers...

Comment: I'd read up about vendor prefixes. -webkit- as its name suggests, is only for webkit based browsers (Chrome, Safari, Android etc). This si a decent read: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-deal-with-vendor-prefixes/

Comment: a simple google search would have answered your question very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because -webkit- is meant to be worked only on chrome and safari. In your code you have,

```
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
```

you need to add to it,

```
 transform:scale(1.1);        //standard one
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1); // for chrome && safari
-moz-transform:scale(1.1);    //for mozilla
-o-transform:scale(1.1);      // for opera
-ms-transform:scale(1.1);;    //for Internet explorer
```

like so, you need to add to all the places wherever you have added -webkit-. Do not forget to add the standard properties as well.

Comment: a clear cut answer. thats all i wanted.

Comment: You are welcome.Make sure you _always_ include the _standard versions_ first.

Answer (score 1):

`-foo-` are prefixes used on CSS properties when they are **experimental** (subject to change and not intended for production use).

Take the prefix off to use the standard version of the property.

Consider duplicating the property with various prefixes (`-webkit-`, `-moz-`, `-o-`, `-ms-`) if you want to risk using the experimental implementations that the browser vendors don't consider read for prime time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `-webkit-` works on webkit browser (chrome including safari) only.

You need the following vendor prefixes:

```
-webkit- /* for chrome */
-moz- /* for firefox */
-o- /* for opera */
-ms- /* for ie */
```

So, you should use like this:

```
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
-moz-transform:scale(1.1);
-o-transform:scale(1.1);
-ms-transform:scale(1.1);
transform:scale(1.1); /*standard way*/
```

Comment: Don't forget safari. `-webkit-` works for safari as well.

Comment: opera > 12 has webkit too

Comment: I don't think that is correct. They are both browsers based on the webkit engine. However, they are two completely different browsers, made by completely different companies. Google Chrome is one browser, and Apple's Safari is another. The only thing they really have in common is the webkit engine.

Comment: Chrome isn't based on webkit any more, it uses blink.

Comment: @Quentin thanks I was unknown about that and that's what standard way do.

Answer (score 0):

> WebKit is a HTML/CSS web browser rendering engine for Safari/Chrome. Are there such engines for IE/Opera/Firefox and what are the differences, pros and cons of using one over the other? Can I use WebKit features in Firefox for example?

Every browser is backed by a rendering engine to draw the HTML/CSS web page.

- IE → [Trident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_%28layout_engine%29)
- Firefox/Seamonkey → [Gecko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29)
- Opera → [Presto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presto_%28layout_engine%29)
- Safari/Chrome → [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit).

See [Comparison of web browser engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browser_engines#See_also) for a list of comparison in different areas.

> The ultimate question... is WebKit supported by IE?

Not natively.

Answer (score 0):

You need a webkit browser to use -webkit- CSS

http://caniuse.com/ is a good reference for CSS, if they need a prefix or not:

http://caniuse.com/border-radius

http://caniuse.com/css-transitions

http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow

http://caniuse.com/css-animation